# Documentation for SimpleForm in luci

Tags: lua, simple-form, openwrt, luci

I try to manipulate the code that generates the config mode in the [freifunk firmware gluon](https://github.com/rubo77/packages/commit/424e6a829a08b02198a3cb9abccc1381802025de) but I cannot find the documentation how to add a TEXTAREA instead of an INPUT field at this lines:

```
o = s:option(Value, "_contact", "Kontakt")
o.default = string.format("%f", uci:get_first("gluon-contact", "contact", "public_info", ""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some documentation here:

http://luci.subsignal.org/trac/wiki/Documentation/CBI

So a textarea is called `TextValue`:

```
o = s:option(TextValue, "_contact", "Kontakt")
o.default = string.format("%s", uci:get_first("gluon-contact", "contact", "public_info", ""))
o.rmempty = false
o.datatype = "string"                                  
o.description = "z.B. E-Mail, Telefon oder Chat-Name"  
o.size = 35
```